Accessing Latest ACC File Version (Later than Published)
I'm working with APS and need to access the absolute latest version of a file in ACC. This version is newer than the one currently published/shared.
Is there a way to do this within APS or do I need to look at other solutions? Any code examples or specific workflows would be greatly appreciated!

You can get the file/ item versions using the endpoint described at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-POST/
